# odp db specific value pull from dataset using powershell

Tags: sql, oracle, powershell, hashtable

I have connected to my oracle db and pulling data using a datatable in dataadapter

My dataadapter output is similar to below

```
NO            NAME                 ID
--------      -----------          ----------
1016859     NO                     78
1016858     NO                     233
1016858     YES                    84
1016858     YES                    59
1016858     NO                     979
1016858     NO                     234
```

But when I try pull the values of Yes it retrieves all the value or null from the table

Below I tried

```
$values=@()
if($result.name -eq "yes")
{
$values+=$result.name
$no=$results.ID
}
$values
```

But it either pulls all the values or only one which is not even a yes..
Is there any way I can pull only No and ID for Name is Yes,like below

Example:

If name is YES

```
No:1016858 and 1016858
No:84 and 59
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming PSv3+:

```
$filteredResult = $result | Where-Object Name -eq 'YES' | Select-Object Name, ID
$filteredResult.NAME  # array of names
$filteredResult.ID    # array of ID values
```